# How to get the playlist that the current user is following in spotify?

Tags: spotify

I wanted to get the playlist that the user is **following** in the spotify api but could not seem to find the way. Can you tell me how to do this ? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment with the **Spotify Web API**, you can only request **all** the **Playlists** that a **User** is **Following** and the **Playlists** created by the **Current User** with [Get a List of Current User's Playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists/).

However you can see what the **Owner** of a **Playlist** is so you could use [Get Current User's Profile](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/users-profile/get-current-users-profile/) to get the profile for the **Current User**. Then get all the **Playlists** with **Get a List of Current User's Playlists** and see which ones have a different **Owner** than the **Current User**, this is the only currently supported way of determining which Playlists a User is Following.

Comment: I was actually doing the same thing but missing the private scope that shows me all the playlists.